# How to get a fields particular value of JSON in python?

Tags: python, json

I am currently working on extracting fields from json and then make some use of that. Hence I have face parameters, and I want to store each field's value. I am trying to fetch the Gender value from a JSON of face :
The JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "face": [
    {
      "attribute": {
        "age": {
          "range": 5,
          "value": 24
        },
        "gender": {
          "confidence": 99.9999,
          "value": "Female"
        },
        "glass": {
          "confidence": 99.4157,
          "value": "None"
        },
        "pose": {
          "pitch_angle": {
            "value": 0.000001
          },
          "roll_angle": {
            "value": 0.650337
          },
          "yaw_angle": {
            "value": -0.42409
          }
        },
        "race": {
          "confidence": 98.058,
          "value": "Asian"
        },
        "smiling": {
          "value": 3.78394
        }
      },
      "face_id": "42245f24335ad21ea7c54f2db96a09b3",
      "position": {
        "center": {
          "x": 50.121951,
          "y": 35.97561
        },
        "eye_left": {
          "x": 43.465122,
          "y": 30.670488
        },
        "eye_right": {
          "x": 56.80878,
          "y": 30.821951
        },
        "height": 27.560976,
        "mouth_left": {
          "x": 45.649512,
          "y": 45.041707
        },
        "mouth_right": {
          "x": 55.134878,
          "y": 44.858049
        },
        "nose": {
          "x": 50.183415,
          "y": 38.410732
        },
        "width": 27.560976
      },
      "tag": ""
    }
  ],
  "img_height": 410,
  "img_id": "1e3007cb3d6cfbaed3a1b4135524ed25",
  "img_width": 410,
  "session_id": "76ec7f99a471418fa8862a2138cc589d",
  "url": "http://www.faceplusplus.com/wp-content/themes/faceplusplus/assets/img/demo/1.jpg?v=2"
}
```

I want to extract 'Female' from the above json.
And for that, I used this :

```
 import urllib2
 import io, json
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 data = soup #soup has all the data json
 with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii=False)
 #content = json.loads(soup)
 jsonFile = open('data.json', 'r')
 values = json.load(jsonFile)
 jsonFile.close()
 gender = soup['face'][0]['gender']['value']
 print gender
```

Where is my code incorrect?

Comment: what error or problem is this code causing? Meaning is it giving a syntax error or printing nothing or etc...

Comment: as a side note, if your json could be more complicated than that, having a query support can make your life much easier: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jq

Comment: I downloaded the package. But I dont know how to correct the error I am getting. It's giving the error! I tried saving the json in a variable as well as a file...

Answer (score 4):

According to your json example , `gender` is inside `attribute` , so you need to access it as -

```
gender = soup['face'][0]['attribute']['gender']['value']
```

Also, seems like `values` is the json that is read back (dictionary), so you may want to access it using `values` , though I am not sure what you are trying to achieve so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: I tried this also, it gives an error, that 
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: and also maybe print out the value of soup just before accessing this and update that

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml.py", line 15, in <module>
    gender = str(soup['face'][0]['attribute']['gender']['value'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
This was the complete traceback.  soup is exactly same as json

Comment: I also tried replacing soup with values. Both give the same error.

Comment: And the print of the soup?

Comment: Well, here is the link to the print of soup and values both...
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11824666

Comment: If that is really your `soup` variable , then the above code should be correct, i tried it and it worked for me, also python does not print out dictionary in such good way, please do `print(soup)` just before the gender getting line and update us with that.

Comment: I will again say the same thing, its showing the same error to me.

Comment: Please check if anybody can suspect the error. I am really confused what  to do..

Comment: Try to print soup['face'] and tell us what you get ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got an answer and it is working perfect.

```
with open('data.json') as da:
    data = json.loads(json.load(da))
print data['face'][0]['attribute']['gender']['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some libraries like **[objectpath](http://objectpath.org/)**, it makes you able to search in JSON in easy way.
just import the library and build the object tree, then type your word that you want to search for.

**Importing:**

```
import json
import objectpath
```

**Building the search tree:**

```
gender_tree = objectpath.Tree(values['face'])
```

**Typing your searching word**

```
gender_tuple = tuple(actions_tree.execute('$..gender'))
```

Now, you can deal with `gender_tuple` for your required values.

Here, the word that you are searching for is "**gender**", replace it with your suitable word for future searches.